# gem install jekyll failed on windows 8 because of stemmer

Tags: ruby

Im trying to install jekyll on windows 8 but its getting failed because of stemmer. Please give me a good solutions.

**Here is my comp config.**

- *Windows 8 Pro 64-bit
- Intel Pentium Dual 1.6Ghz
- 2GB RAM*

**and version of ruby and gem.**

```
$ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [i386-mingw32]

$ gem --version
2.4.6
```

**Even I have installed Ruby DevKit**

DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx

**And this is what im getting while installing Jekyll.**

```
    $ gem install jekyll
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150302-1732-9b3i52.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
generating stemmer-i386-mingw32.def
compiling porter.c
porter.c: In function 'step1ab':
porter.c:233:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
porter.c:234:7: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'
.
.
.
.
.
.
porter.c:238:4: warning: passing argument 2 of 'ends' discards 'const' qualifier
 from pointer target type [enabled by default]
porter.c:182:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'

compiling porter_wrap.c
In file included from c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from porter_wrap.c:1:
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:109:14: error: size of array 'ruby_chec
k_sizeof_voidp' is negative
In file included from c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from porter_wrap.c:1:
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_obj_wb_unprotect':
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1234:9: warning: cast to pointer from i
nteger of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1235:6: warning: cast to pointer from i
nteger of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1238:2: warning: cast to pointer from i
nteger of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_obj_written':
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1253:9: warning: cast to pointer from i
nteger of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_num2char_inline':
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1324:35: warning: cast to pointer from
integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1324:35: warning: cast to pointer from
integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1324:35: warning: cast to pointer from
integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1325:9: warning: cast to pointer from i
nteger of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1325:9: warning: cast to pointer from i
nteger of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1325:9: warning: cast to pointer from i
nteger of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_class_of':
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1642:12: warning: cast to pointer from
integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h: In function 'rb_type':
c:/Ruby21/include/ruby-2.1.0/ruby/ruby.h:1659:12: warning: cast to pointer from
integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
porter_wrap.c: In function 'stem_word':
porter_wrap.c:26:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W
int-to-pointer-cast]
porter_wrap.c:26:16: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-W

int-to-pointer-cast]
porter_wrap.c:28:7: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi

nt-to-pointer-cast]
porter_wrap.c:28:7: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wi
nt-to-pointer-cast]
porter_wrap.c:20:17: warning: unused variable 'i' [-Wunused-variable]
make: *** [porter_wrap.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fast-stemm
er-1.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/fas
t-stemmer-1.0.2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows is not officially supported by Jekyll, and will need some tweaks in order to run.

Check out Jekyll's [helpful guide](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/) to get started.

Comment: Issue Resolved.

Jekyll is installed in my comp. it was a mistaken by installation mismatched  version of Ruby and DevKit.

Need to add proper certificate 
Read here - [link](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88) 
-
_____
-
@RobWagner : Without knowing anything don't put your comments as well as simply don't do Vote Down if you have common sense.